# How to dynamically allocate array of structures in c?

Tags: c, file, memory-management, struct, linked-list

I want to implement a simple word counting program which will open a
text file, which is supplied as a command line argument, and then count the number of words,
number of non-alphabetical word (ex : 1998, 2-3, and so on) sentences and paragraphs in that text
file. Assuming a character array between two spaces counts as a word and non-alphabetical words consist of numbers, hyphens, etc. Each sentence finishes with a ‘.’ (dot) char, whereas paragraphs are
separated with newlines. I will use a structure that holds word count, nonalphabetical
word count, sentence count and starting line for each paragraph like so:

```
    struct {
      int word;
      int sentence;
      int nonAlpha;
      int startingLine;
      struct Paragraph*next;       
    }Paragraph;
```

I decided to use linked lists for this one. So should I itterate and learn how many paragraphs will be used and initialize the linked list ,link them and or just keep allocating if there is a new paragraph read from file and needs to be stored in a structure?

```
    Paragraph->next=(struct Paragraph*) calloc(1,sizeof(struct Paragraph));
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want a solution where you can increment the size as the file is read?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I dynamically allocate it without giving SIZE?

You can't allocate a contiguous array without knowing the size.

I'll give you a few options:

1. Pre-allocate in a large size chunk using `malloc` and copy into it. If you run out of size while reading your file `realloc` a larger size chunk.
2. Count the number of words in the file first, `malloc` that much, and then read the file again.
3. Use a linked list structure. `malloc` for each word and have a pointer to the next.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Paragraph *dynamicParagraph = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(Paragraph));
```

And since in C/C++ arrays and pointers are basically the same thing, you can use it as an array:

```
Paragraph specificParagraph = dynamicParagraph[index]; //Assuming index < SIZE and > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want one `struct` instance per paragraph.  So, each time you encounter a newline character, you want to start a new paragraph count.

Start by dynamically allocating an initial number of `Paragraph` objects (enough to cover most cases), and then extend that block as necessary:

```
#define INITIAL_SIZE ... // some initial value, say 5 or 10
...
size_t numParas = 0;     // keep track of the array size
size_t parasRead = 0;    // keep track of the paragraphs read
...
struct Paragraph *paras = malloc(sizeof *paras * INITIAL_SIZE);
if (paras)
{
  numParas = INITIAL_SIZE;
}
else
{
   perror("Could not allocate initial memory...exiting");
   exit(-1);
}

... // open the file and read input

while (more_data)
{
  int c = fgetc(input);

  // update the various fields of paras[parasRead]
  // based on the value of current_character

  if (c == '\n')
  {
    // ready to start a new paragraph.  If we've reached the end
    // of the paras array and don't have a new slot available,
    // extend the array by doubling its size
    if (parasRead + 1 == numParas)
    {
      struct Paragraph *tmp = realloc(paras, sizeof *paras * (numParas * 2));
      if (tmp)
      {
        paras = tmp;
        numParas *= 2;
      }
      else
      {
        perror("Could not extend the paras array...exiting");
        free(paras);
        exit(-1);
      }
    }
    parasRead++;
    moreData = (c != EOF);
  }
}

// display results
...
free(paras);
```

That should at least get you started.  You'll have to decide what to do if `realloc` can't extend your buffer.  In the example code above I treat it as a fatal error and exit immediately, but you can try to extend the buffer by a smaller amount (instead of doubling, increase it by 1.5 times, and if that fails then 1.25 times, etc.).  You can decide to exit the loop and present what results you have.  Or something completely different.

There's also probably a better way to organize this; it would be better to segregate the array management code into a separate function.  But this should give you a flavor of what's required.

Answer (score 0):

Use linked list instead of array. In this case you'll only need to allocate new members when they are needed.